# Access React Component within a function from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need a little help. I am trying to access a component from a function within another component.

```
var Test = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (<div className="test"> <p> Some Text </p> </div>)
    }
});

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (<Grid onClick = {this.calendar} />)
    },
    calendar: function(){
        <Test />
    }
});

React.render(<App />, document.body)
```

I am trying to access the Test component. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: what is show doing? is that like a onclick thing?

Comment: essentially I am trying to access Test by clicking @JohnRuddell

Comment: Why is your code indented so strangely? If you expect others to read your code and help you, you can at least format it correctly.

Comment: -__- @FelixKling treat it like psuedo code

Comment: I also expect pseudo code to be properly formatted. Seriously, if you cannot even put a little effort in your question why should others put effort into answering it?

Comment: ok are you done yet? I got your point... by the way thanks for react :) @FelixKling

Comment: @Roddrick instead of being snarky.. you should apologize and edit your question and format it. that way when others come to the question they can be helped better (for later when someone else has the same issue).

Comment: sorry guys @JohnRuddell

Comment: @Roddrick its ok, but please format your question. if you look at my answer and see how its formatted, try and follow that. it would make your question a ton better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what your show is doing but generally if you want to render a component inside another theres two things u can do... either pass it though as a unique prop or as a child by writing it inside the parent component.. I'll show you the second option since thats usually how you should / would do it

```
return (
    <Grid>
        <Test />
    </Grid> 
);
```

or if its conditional

```
render: function(){
    return ( 
        <Grid onClick={this.setSomeBool}>
            {this.state.someBool ? <Test /> : null}
        </Grid> 
    );
},
setSomeBool: function(){
    this.setState({someBool: !this.state.someBool});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but in my getInitialState function Im getting " getInitialState must return an object.

Comment: @Roddrick you obviously don't know what you are doing with react. I would recommend you look at the examples and tutorials facebook has.... to help you with this just think about the error.. getInitialState must return an object.. that means that you are not returning an object in getInitialState... an object is {} and you arent returning it with the return key word. in this example... `return {someBool: false};` would do the trick